# How to check if an Ad has a "Poor Ads Experience" using facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

In Facebook Ads Manager under the Delivery column, some ads are marked as "Poor Ads Experience". I'm looking for a way to get all Active ads that are marked with "Poor Ads Experience". I could not find the right endpoint for this.
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/hriAd.jpg
When I mouse over I see a message "Based on 7-day click and 1-day view attribution window". But that doesn't help much.
Can someone tell me how I can get all ads marked with  "Poor Ads Experience" from Facebook API?